# Receiving empty list from realm when I launch the android application for the first time.

Tags: android, parse-platform, kotlin, realm

I have a separate class to do database operations and I am inserting the data into realm which I receive from Parse Platform and in my Main Activity I am retrieving the data from Realm and as I do this when I launch the application for the first time I am receiving an empty list but when I close the application and reopen I have the full list
    This is my insert function

```
    fun insertUserIntoDb(name: String, id: String, detail : String) {

        realm.executeTransaction {
            val stream: Stream = realm.createObject(Stream::class.java, 
            id)
            stream.name = name
            stream.detail = detail
        }
    }

 This is my getData function


 fun getUserFromDb() : ArrayList<Stream> {
    val list = ArrayList<Stream>()
    val streams: RealmResults<Stream> = 
    realm.where(Stream::class.java).findAll()
    list.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(streams))

    //Log.d("", "path: " + realm.get

Path())
        return list
    }
```

Comment: Has the data from the Parse platform definitely been received, parsed, and entered into the Realm before `getData` is called for the first time?

Comment: Yes I debugged the application and first the insert is performed and data is entered into Realm and then Get method is called and when the application is launched for the first time RealmResults is empty.

Comment: Unfortunately debugging can cause false positives when dealing with multiple threads - while your debugger is blocking one thread, another thread can be running and carry out an operation that would normally not be done before the first thread needs the result of that operation. Perhaps try simply logging instead and see if you get the same result? :)

Comment: I am sorry that I did not mention I put a Log message before insert method and also a Log message before Get method and I have the same result.

Comment: When dealing with multiple threads and Realm, you need to use Realm notifications to know when does the Realm db version change on the dedicated thread. see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

Comment: @beeender Thank You I will go through the documentation.